# Java Quarkus using Redis as a Cache with UUID keys

Tags: java, redis, quarkus, uuid

Hello i'm having an issue with the `java.util.UUID` object in a redis cache. I have a cache defined as follows

```java
    private final ValueCommands<UUID, String> commands;

    public Cache(RedisDataSource ds) {
        this.commands = ds.value(UUID.class, String.class);
    }

    public String get(UUID key) {
        var value = commands.get(key);
    }
```

This does not work. the get command is unable to find any values with that key.

So my question is, is UUID not supported? Should I always prefer the string key value pair?

```java
    private final ValueCommands<String, String> commands;

    public Cache(RedisDataSource ds) {
        this.commands = ds.value(String.class, String.class);
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        var value = commands.get(key);
    }
```

doing it like this works.

I'm testing this by connecting to the redis CLI and inputing a value with

`SET 38e8598b-e700-440c-b92f-b2d078d6fb5f "hello"`

then calling `cache.get` and this does not work with UUID as shown above but this work with String

EDIT based on comment based on @for_stack

The issue seems to be coming from if the key is not set by the quarkus application for example this works with UUID

```java
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public String getFromRedis() {
    cache.set(
      UUID.fromString("32e8598b-e700-440c-b92f-b2d078d6fb5f"),
      "hello-world"
    );
    return cache.get(UUID.fromString("32e8598b-e700-440c-b92f-b2d078d6fb5f"));
  }
```

but if i use the CLI to set the key to 32e8598b-e700-440c-b92f-b2d078d6fb5f it will not work

EDIT 2

The string key value from the CLI is different from the one set from quarkus

`"\"12e8598b-e700-440c-b92f-b2d078d6fb5f\""` is the one quarkus set with UUID

and when you set it from CLI its `"12e8598b-e700-440c-b92f-b2d078d6fb5f"`

Comment: Redis has no idea on UUID, you need to serialize `java.util.UUID` to string before setting it to Redis.